# Icenium no provisioning profile found

Tags: iphone, ios, icenium

I’ve recently downloaded an installed Icenium Graphite (free for 30 days) on my Windows 7, 64 bit. I’ve created a new project (Cross-Platform Device Application jQueryMobile).

My iPhone is plugged in and I can see my device in the *Devices* panel at the bottom of the IDE.

When I *Run-->On device*, I obtain an error which basically tells me that I don’t have any **provisions**.

After several searches, articles and youtube videos, I still can’t get my head around this.
I’ve logged into the apple developer center. It appears I need to enroll and pay 99$ a year as an individual.

If my plan is to eventually publish my application to the Apple Store than I understand the 99$/year fee but if my goal is to simply test locally on my iPhone how can I do this without enrolling?

Is it even possible or the 99$/year is a must regardless if I only plan on testing locally?
If anyone could help me shed some light on this that would be great!

Sincerely

PS: My iPhone is not jailbroken so I can’t use the approaches found in some articles I’ve read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Icenium Ion to run your app on your iPhone without the need of provision. You can get it from here - https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/icenium-ion/id527547398?mt=8 Also, you don't need to jailbreak your phone to use the app.

What you need to do is the following:
Run Graphite, open your project, connect your device, verify that Graphite recognizes it and fire up Ion on your mobile device. Your app should be loaded automatically. Also, check if in Graphite Ion LiveSync is enabled for your device.

You can check docs.icenium.com for even more details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! The info you provided really helped and it works!
The only thing is that in the Ion start up screen it mentions (for Graphite) to click "Run on device" which is not needed. If I do "Run on device" from the Icenium IDE, I get the same No provisioning profile found error.
My guess is to stick to your steps which do not require a "Run on device".
Sincerely, thanks!